# is possible to face recognition with mediapipe in python

Tags: python, mediapipe

I try to make app with python to be able recognition face, recently use cv2+dlib and face_recognition module for recognition, but i have two problems:

1. have 3 or 4 second delay
2. low accuracy

That's why I decided to use another library, after so many search, find [MediaPipe](https://mediapipe.dev/), this library is very fast (real time) and find [this example](https://google.github.io/mediapipe/solutions/face_detection#python-solution-api) for face detection, but I need face recognition! but not found any example for face recognition
Is there a solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mediapipe doesn't provide a face recognition method, only face detector.

The face_recognition library has really good accuracy, It's claimed accuracy is 99%+. your dataset probably isn't good enough.

**Solutions:**

1. For better speed performance, use the "hog" model instead of "cnn" model. you can modify it when you use the face_locations method like the following code line.

   ```
   locations = face_recognition.face_locations(frame, model="hog")
   ```
2. For accuracy, use better dataset images (higher quality, a face looking straight at the camera, more pictures for the same person but usually 1-3 pictures is enough)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to increase the accuracy of face recognization reduce the tolerance value to 0.4 or 0.5 and for face detection use the hog model.

```py
face_recognition.api.compare_faces(known_face_encodings,face_encoding_to_check, tolerance=0.5)
```

https://face-recognition.readthedocs.io/en/latest/face_recognition.html